# image for reset action

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using an image instead of a reset button n html-php.I wrote a  javascriptfunction to clear all the text box values,but it reloads the entire page,so that again the values appear in the textbox when reloading the page,when the image button for reset action is clicked ..
My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearall() {
$(".tinput").val('');
$(".tinput1").val('');
}
</script>
```

I dont want the page to reload,but just clear all text fields only.

Comment: show your html code with image

Comment: I guess you wrapper image within <a> tag ? If so, make your function return FALSE;

Comment: e.preventDefault(); may work for you?

Comment: the html code is<input type="image" src="images/clear.png" id="reset" />

Comment: no,i tried it all,bt its still not working...

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearall() {
$(".tinput").val('');
$(".tinput1").val('');
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your form is being submitted.

You need to stop the default action of the button and to do this you must call the `.preventDefault()` method on the event or `return false` from the handler.

You shoul also use the form's `.reset()` method..

```
function resetForm(callingElement) {
   callingElement.form.reset();
   return false;
}
```

and use it with `<input type="image" src=".." onclick="return resetForm(this)" />`

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/3R2TX/

---

Since you are using jQuery you could simplify this to

```
function resetForm(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.form.reset();
}
```

and apply it with

```
 $('#id_of_reset_button').click(resetForm);
```

**jQuery Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/3R2TX/1/

Comment: there must be other code interfering.. (*make sure you run the code a fter the DOM is loaded*).. a live link would help..

Answer (score 0):

When having a hyperlink or submit button, your function must return FALSE in order to stop being processed

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="reset" src="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#reset").click(function(){
    $(".tinput").val('');
    $(".tinput1").val('');
  });
</script>
```